# get windows file modification time

Tags: windows, windows-command-prompt

Under Windows, running 'DIR' in the command prompt shows a file's last modified time to the nearest minute. For example:

```
17.10.2011  14:55           115 638 pgstat.stat
```

How do I get more accurate results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-desktop/date-modified-to-show-time-with-seconds/5ec0ea23-776e-4163-8106-4651c7c6af4a

> Here's what I did... Download the Google Chrome browser if you're not
>   using it already (it's very good) and paste the path into the address
>   box. Your directory contents will be listed with the modified time
>   down to the seconds.

Comment: not actually a command, but works for me!

Comment: I haven't tested it, did it actually work?